# Cloudwatch alert for HTTP 500 status code || Windows IIS logs

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, http-status-code-500

We have one app running on windows server. We are receiving intermediate 500 status code error in windows server IIS logs. We monitor this IIS logs on CloudWatch logs console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEirs.png)

We want to configure the alert whenever 500 status code observe in IIS logs in cloudwatch console it should sent us email via SNS.

We tried creating the metric with following filter patterns
Filter Pattern-
[host, logName, user, timestamp, request, statusCode=5*, size], Also try with Filter pattern- "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
Set Metric Value as 1 and default value as 0 then configured Alarm for this metrics.
But for both Filter pattern We did not received the alert even 500 status code was still showing in IIS logs.

How we can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to found the solution of it.

On windows server, I have configured failed request tracing in IIS.

Link for reference-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Post configuration, FailedRequestLogs folder was got created in IIS logs path.
Inside this folder it stores all failed request status codes logs 4xx, 5xx etc.

I then push this logs to cloudwatch using aws system manager.

I was able to filter 500 status codes from the logs stored on cloudwatch. Then I just configured the Metric and alarm and it works!

Post that I am able to receive all request failed logs on email through SNS configured on cloudwatch.